# Drill down into relevant SUMIFS when multiple SUMIFS are nested in an IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script to drill down into a cell containing a SUMIFS, and then filter the raw data sheet to isolate the rows pertaining. The script works on a cell that has just one SUMIFS.

Some of my cells contain an IF statement with two SUMIFS (depending on what variable the IF is).

I am trying to find a way to first find the relevant SUMIFS in the IF statement, and then use the correct one to then filter.

My code:

1. Double click script loaded on worksheet to trigger the macro (this is working)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    FilterBySUMIFs Target.Cells(1)
End Sub
```

2. Script loaded to Module for the SUMIFS

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FilterBySUMIFs(r As Range)

   Dim v, ctr As Integer
   Dim intField As Integer, intPos As Integer
   Dim strCrit As String
   Dim rngCritRange1 As Range, rngSUM As Range
   Dim wksDataSheet As Worksheet

   If Not r.Formula Like "*SUMIFS(*" Then Exit Sub

   'split formula by comma, strip the right paren
   v = Split(Left(r.Formula, Len(r.Formula) - 1), ",")

   'the first criteria range is the 2nd element of the array
   Set rngCritRange1 = Range(v(LBound(v) + 1))

   'use first criteria range to get a reference to the data sheet
   With rngCritRange1
       Set wksDataSheet = Workbooks(.Parent.Parent.Name).Worksheets(.Parent.Name)
   End With

   'clear any existing filter, turn filtering on if needed
   With wksDataSheet
       If .AutoFilterMode And .FilterMode Then
           'clear existing autofilter
           .ShowAllData
       ElseIf Not .AutoFilterMode Then
           'display autofilter arrows
           rngCritRange1.CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
       End If
   End With

   'set the filters
   For ctr = LBound(v) + 1 To UBound(v)
       If ctr Mod 2 <> 0 Then
           With wksDataSheet
               'determine field in case table does not start in column A
               intField = .Range(v(ctr)).Column - .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).Column + 1
               'use evaluate instead of range(v(ctr + 1))
               'so both cell-reference and hard-coded criteria are handled.
               strCrit = Evaluate(v(ctr + 1))
               .Range(v(ctr)).AutoFilter Field:=intField, Criteria1:=strCrit
           End With
       End If
   Next

   'strip left paren and everything to left of it,
   ' get the sum range from first element of array
   intPos = InStr(1, v(LBound(v)), "(")
   Set rngSUM = Range(Replace(v(LBound(v)), Left(v(LBound(v)), intPos), ""))
   'select the SUM range so total displays in status bar
   Application.Goto rngSUM

   ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1

End Sub

Sub KV_FilterBySumIf()

End Sub
```

My SUMIFS looks as follows:

```
=IF($C$6="ALL",SUMIFS(IS!Actual_Total,IS!Curr_Bud,H$9,IS!Master_Sub_Account,$C14),SUMIFS(IS!Actual_Total,IS!Curr_Bud,H$9,IS!Master_Sub_Account,$C14,IS!Project_Desc,$C$6))
```

Comment: Noted, thank you!

Comment: Side Note: Since `v` is created by `Split`. The LBound is guaranteed to be 0, so `v(LBound(v) + 1)` is the same as `v(1)`.

Comment: When you say "drill down", what do you mean? I was looking for a Pivot Table [DrillDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.drilldown) and didn't find any pivot tables or `drilldown` methods.

Comment: Essentially the script performs a similar task as drilling down in a pivot table does. Except this script allows for the same function on a cell containing a SUMIFS and not a pivot table. The above code when double clicked with filter the relevant rows in the raw data so the user can see what transactions made up that amount. I just need it to do the same, but first cater for the IF statement, and then use either the SUMIFS for TRUE, or SUMIFS for FALSE.

Comment: My original comment was not correct, the line `Set wksDataSheet = Workbooks(.Parent.Parent.Name).Worksheets(.Parent.Name)` is equivalent to `Set wksDataSheet = rngCritRange1.Parent`. Originally I said `r.Parent`, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a function that can split the IF formula into it's TRUE and FALSE parts and return relevant part based on the expression. So if the expression is true, the function returns the True part of the IF Formula.

The function I have made is not a robust function, and it only works if the given formula is in the structure of "=IF(< expression >, SUMIFS(...), SUMIFS(...))". And it evaluates the expression with the `ActiveSheet`.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim SumIfsFormula As String
    SumIfsFormula = "=IF($C$6=""ALL"",SUMIFS(IS!Actual_Total,IS!Curr_Bud,H$9,IS!Master_Sub_Account,$C14),SUMIFS(IS!Actual_Total,IS!Curr_Bud,H$9,IS!Master_Sub_Account,$C14,IS!Project_Desc,$C$6))"

    Debug.Print RelevantSumIfs(SumIfsFormula)
    'Output when TRUE : SUMIFS(IS!Actual_Total,IS!Curr_Bud,H$9,IS!Master_Sub_Account,$C14)
    'Output when FALSE : SUMIFS(IS!Actual_Total,IS!Curr_Bud,H$9,IS!Master_Sub_Account,$C14,IS!Project_Desc,$C$6)
End Sub

Function RelevantSumIfs(SumIfsFormula As String) As String
    Dim IfResult As Boolean
    IfResult = Application.Evaluate("=" & Split(Split(SumIfsFormula, "(")(1), ",")(0))
    
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "SUMIFS\([^)]+\)"
    End With
    
    Dim Matches As Object
    Set Matches = regex.Execute(SumIfsFormula)
    
    Dim TargetSumIfs
    If IfResult Then
        TargetSumIfs = Matches(0)
    Else
        TargetSumIfs = Matches(1)
    End If
    
    RelevantSumIfs = TargetSumIfs
End Function
```

This function could be improved by changing the Regex pattern from explicitly searching for `SUMIFS` to searching for any function. Something like `.Pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]+\([^)]+\)"`. But this may also match many other parts of the formula, including the surrounding `IF(...)`. Which is why I left it as `.Pattern = "SUMIFS\([^)]+\)"`

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I'm not great at VBA, my above code was built over time, using snippets. Please explain - will I now replace the r.Formula (in my above second script) with RelevantSumIfs(SumIfsFormula)? I get errors when I do. Perhaps I'm not incorporating the function properly?

Comment: You would replace `r.Formula` with `RelevantSumIfs( r.Formula )` that way you're plugging the current formula into the function, which would then return to you the relevant portion of the formula. But my function will fail if the formula is just `SUMIFS(...)` and not `IF( ..., SUMIFS(...), SUMIFS(...))`. So you will want to test for that first, to decide if you should proceed using `r.Formula` or `RelevantSumIfs( r.Formula )` .

Comment: Perfect! Works just as I need it to. Thank you for assisting. Using the function to first handle the logic is a great tool.